# boto3 sqs incorrect url when not specified endpoint url

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sqs, boto

Do I always need to specify `endpoint_url` when creating boto3 client?
Why can't I specify `QueueUrl` as method argument?

```py
# boto3==1.16.51
import boto3


client = boto3.client('sqs')

messages = client.receive_message(
    QueueUrl='https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/325672072888/event-queue-test',
    WaitTimeSeconds=2,
    MaxNumberOfMessages=1,
    AttributeNames=["All"],
)
```

Exception:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAddress)
> when calling the ReceiveMessage operation:  The address
> https://eu-central-1.queue.amazonaws.com/ is not valid for this
> endpoint.

Seems like it takes default values for sqs queue. But why it does not take value from `QueueUrl`

Comment: `endpoint_url` and `QueueUrl` are two different things. The error says that `QueueUrl` is incorrect.

Comment: @Marcin But `https://eu-central-1.queue.amazonaws.com/` url is not the same as QueueUrl specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url from the error msg is different then `QueueUrl` because AWS CLI and boto3 use **legacy endpoint**, one of which is `eu-central-1.queue.amazonaws.com`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sqs-service.html):

> If you use the AWS CLI or SDK for Python, you can use the following **legacy endpoints**.

You can check this using:

```
print(client._endpoint)
```

Comment: Thanks for response.
My question is a little bit different.
Why does not it work when I specify the full `QueueUrl`?

Should I always specify `boto3.client('sqs', endpoint_url='...')`?

Comment: @johanson Your `QueueUrl` must be is incorrect. It is independent of `endpoint_url`. Correct `QueueUrl` works both with legacy and current `endpoint_url` endpoints.